# Add a Mouseover Event Dynamically on a HTML Element

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML element like this:

```
<div id="new"></div>
```

I want to append a onmouseover function to append text to this element like this:

```
<div id="new" onmouseover="show_pop()"></div>
```

What is the jQuery function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
$('#new').mouseover(function() {show_popup();});
```

Or, if you REALLY want it to actually add that to the node (which you probably don't), then something like:

```
$('#new').attr('onmouseover', 'show_popup()');
```